# Distribution of a binary matrix times a Bernoulli vector

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

Suppose we have the vector $\mathbf{Y} = (Y_{1},\ldots,Y_{n})$
where $Y_{i} \sim \textrm{Bernoulli}(p_{i})$ independently.
For the applications I have in mind, $n$ will typically be
several thousand, and each $p_{i}$ will be small.

We also have a fixed $n \times p$ (with $p$ usually around $100-200$) 
matrix $\mathbf{Z}$, where
the $(i,j)$ element $Z_{ij}$ has $Z_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$. 
Typically, this matrix is quite sparse with 
$\sum_{j} Z_{ij}$ usually less than $p/50$.

My interest is in the distribution of $\mathbf{X}$, where
$\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{Z}\mathbf{Y}$.

I believe that the
$i^{th}$ component of $\mathbf{X}$ can be well-approximated
by a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda_{i} = \sum_{j} Z_{ij}p_{j}$,
but is there any way to compute the joint distribution or come up with a sensible approximation to the joint distribution of $\mathbf{X}$?

Comment: Something appears wrong as regards the dimensions here, please check. Is $Y$ a row or column vector?"